# "You need a higher level of permission" after admin changing. Why?

Tags: multisite, theme-customizer

I can't edit my website, when I try to edit, I see the page with the message:

```
You need a higher level of permission.
Sorry, you are not allowed to customize this site.
```

It was started when I create a new super admin user and delete an old user with ID_1 (which was created when WordPress is installed). Now I have a super admin user but can't edit the website. 
I tried deactivating all plugins, but it does not help.

How to fix it?

Comment: Hi Artem, did you fix this issue? We are having the same problem

Comment: Hello. In my case it was cookies. Wrong cookies patches.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Admin user getting message 'You need a higher level of permission'](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/337334/admin-user-getting-message-you-need-a-higher-level-of-permission)

Answer (score -1):

Try to give yourself admin rights programmatically by placing this snippet in your `functions.php`.

```
add_action('init', function(){
    // use your user id
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $yourUserId);

    // Give yourself the admin role
    $user->add_role( 'administrator' );
});
```

Comment: This is the first thing what I did. If everything was so simple, I would not ask =) But anyway thanks for the answer.

I found that the problem is most likely with cookies on a multisite, but where exactly I do not know yet.

Comment: The same thing happened to me after migrating a single site to multisite. Thanks to @ArtemKotov's comment I cleared the cookies in the browser. Boom.

Comment: User is already administrator then why error occurred?

Comment: @MakarandMane, corrupt cookies is the most likely answer. That was my error too in a Multisite where the server had some issues and had to be reset.