# Admin user getting message 'You need a higher level of permission'

Tags: login

I’ve just created my new WordPress web site ( uttoxeter.com ) It worked well for a while but now if I try to modify / edit anything I get asked to log in again and when I do it says that I’ve successfully logged in but after approx 5 seconds I’m logged out again.
If I do manage to get logged in I can make changes but when I hit ‘Publish’ I get a message : ‘You need a higher level of permission’ – ‘ Sorry you are not allowed to customize this site’
How can that be if I’m the site Administrator ?
I’m stuck – please advise how to proceed

Comment: This sounds pretty suspicious to me.  I would suggest contacting your hosting company ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for that - I will do.

Comment: My other (few) WordPress websites on my server are working fine on my own servers. I only have 1 plugin which I now wonder about ( Ultra Community )

Comment: Interestingly if I deactivate the Ultra Community Plugin then all is fine. I guess there is some conflict around the Administrator account.

Comment: @DavidSargeant but it's very suspicious behavior.

Answer (score 2):

[Answers in comments here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/306673/48996) solved this one for me:

**Clear cookies for the site in your browser.**

Comment: Clearing cookie worked for me